# BufferStrategy and Graphics g

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent, bufferstrategy

I have a sprite sheet that I want to use in a src folder within the project. Here is some code I have for a simple game I am making. I get an error when trying to draw anything with the paintbrush or (g). Can you help me figure out what is wrong?

I have a pre-existing background that I want to draw the images over. I deleted the code, the background image isn't what's causing the issues.

```
package NewCards;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private boolean live = false; //running
private boolean dead = false;


//instances of external classes here.

private Thread thread;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
//initialize here.
public void init() {

    }

private synchronized void start() {
    if (running)
        return;
    live = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop() {
    if(!running)
        return;

    try {
        thread.join(); //attempts to join threads, if unsuccessful, throw Exception error.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}

public void run() {
    init();
    long lasttime = System.nanoTime(); 
    final double amountofticks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountofticks;
    double delta = 0;
    int update = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lasttime) / ns;
        lasttime = now;
        if (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            update++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;

        System.out.println(update + " Frames, FPS: " + frames);
        update = 0; // resets fps for updates. If not the beats would just double.
        frames = 0; // statement above applies here in terms of FPS
        }
    }
    stop();
}   

private void tick(){


}

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs== null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;

    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.fillRect(1, 1, 200, 500);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Game game = new Game(); //game starter.

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Game frame = new Game();
                JLabel backgroundImage = new JLabel();
                backgroundImage.setSize(800, 800);
                frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundImage);

                Image background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Artificial intelligence.png")).getImage();
                backgroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(background));
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            game.start();
        }
    }); 
}
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Game() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 800);
    setTitle("MyEmpire-1.1.1/Windows/Display/Menus/Loop");
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
}
}
```

Comment: What's the specific error you are getting?

Comment: IComponent$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy(Component$FlipBufferStrategy).createBuffers(int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available

Comment: Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy(Component$FlipBufferStrategy).createBuffers(int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available 
Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy(Component$FlipBufferStrategy).<init>(Component, int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available 
Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component, int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available 
Game(Component).createBufferStrategy(int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available 
Game(Window).createBufferStrategy(int, BufferCapabilities) line: not available 
Game(Component).createBufferStrategy(int) line: not available

Comment: Game(Window).createBufferStrategy(int) line: not available 
Game.render() line: 119 
Game.run() line: 92 
Thread.run() line: not available 
 All these issues. When I run the program without the BufferStrategy, it works.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you are calling getBufferStrategy before you have called createBufferStrategy. The Java docs do it in the opposite order, so maybe try switching them around.

Comment: Na nothing. Do you think it has to do with how I am using the JFrame? I didn't create it manually I used the wizard within Eclipse.